# How to add css class to these form fields?

Tags: theming, forms, nodes

I wan to be able to add certain css class to all the text fields in my content edit forms. here is a picture of what i can see using Devel:
[image]

Those arrays under the "Und" are for the fields I want to add the class. I have tried to do this with the following:

```
function iclub_form_article_node_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state) {
dpm($form);
$form['field_body']['und']['0']['#attributes']['class'][] ='addRecactor';

foreach ($form['field_paragraph']['und'] as $i) {
    if (is_numeric($i)) {
        echo $i .'</br>';
        $form['field_paragraph']['und'][$i]['field_myparagraph']['und']['0']['#attributes']['class'][] ='addRecactor';
        foreach ($form['field_paragraph']['und'][$i]['field_myparagraph']['und'] as $y) {
            if (is_numeric($y)){
                $form['field_paragraph']['und'][$i]['field_myparagraph']['und'][$y]['#attributes']['class'][] ='addRecactor';
            }
        }   
    }           
}
```

but this does not work for all the fields and I think it is not the solution as it is not robust.

How may I be able to add the class to these fields?

Answer (score 1):

You should write a statement that first check the form element type then add class attrubutes to it,
something like 
//in form_alter

```
foreach($form as $form_elem){
if($form-elem['#type']=='textfield'){
    $form[$form_elem]['#attributes']['class'][] = 'myclass';
   }
}
```

(this is not the exact solution,I just want give you idea)

another way is using [`hook_preprocess_field`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7)

and the final and easy way is using js to add class, because drupal set default class for his textfields,you just need one line jquery code to add you

```
   $('.form-text').addClass('myclass');
```

if you don't want this js not load in all page, I suggest you add your js with `drupal_add_js` conditionally in `hook_form_alter`, it means that

```
    //in hook_form_alter
     $des_forms=array('node_add_page','node_add_prodcut');
    if(in_array($from_id,$des_forms)){
    drupal_add_js('your js'); //you also add it inline,but I suggest you put it in js and add it as file
}
```

**again I tell you because I have no time in this moment I just suggest you some solution idea, I hope could help you**

Answer (score 0):

```
$form['name']['#attributes']['class'] = array('class' => 'formInput formInputB');
```

Try this

Comment: What do you mean by _'name'_? please take into consideration that the number of fields are not limited and user can add any number of them during content creation. So I need a loop which adds the class to each field.

Comment: $delta = 0;
$max_delta = $form['field_set_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#path_to_array'];
while ($delta <= count($max_delta)) {
$form['field_name']['#attributes']['class'] = array('class' => 'formInput formInputB');
$delta++;
}